# How do you determine whether to use random intercept or slope in Generalized Linear Mixed Models?

Tags: modeling, glmm

As in, how do you come up with a linear predictor when using Generalized Linear Mixed Models (before doing model diagnostics)?

Are there exploratory methods or graphs to come up with a model before validating it?

Comment: Look first at your substantive understanding of the data generating process.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_selection

Comment: @ Marjin Weterings: Yes, I know about model selection. My question about about coming up with possible models before model selection / goodness-of-fit. Are there reasonable graphical ways to decide on the linear predictor rather than pick an arbitrary additive one?